# PathGemoetry resizing issue in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, pathgeometry

I want to resize my pathgeometry figure according to screen size set by user.
Basically want to update the figure dynamically or make it responsive.

Currently I am having figure like

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="path1" Figures="M 100,0 A 100,100 0 0 1 100,250" />
```

I am using this path as:

```
<Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="5" Data="{StaticResource path1}"/>
```

I want to make this path resized according to my screen size.Please suggest

Comment: Screen size, window size, and resolution are all completely different things. What is it that you actually want? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried already to solve your problem, along with a precise, clear explanation of what that code does, and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have edited the post, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is a Viewbox with Horizontal(Vertical)Alignment set to stretch.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not necessary when you can just set the Stretch property of the Path.